# PHP HTML Form Encode + Sign?

Tags: php, html, forms, encode

I have a API based search tool created in PHP and running inside of an iframe on a WordPress powered site. Users fill out the search form and using the .POST function upon click submit the information is passed to the second page which populated a URL and returns JSON results.

For some reason my form no longer treats spaces as plus signs. I've search high and low and I'm not sure if it's WordPress or the server itself. My code or something else at play.

I'm wondering if there it a way to force or direct the browser to treat the spaces as + signs?

Ultimate problem is the search criteria needs to pass + signs onto the next page fboResults.php and does not.

Here's my form...

```
<form name="search action="fboResults.php" method="post">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <lable for="searchTerm">Search Criteria: </label>
            <input type="text" name="searchTerm"/></br></br>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <lable for="searchBy">Search By:</label>
            <select name="searchBy">
                <option value="FBO" selected="selected">FBO</option>
                <option value="grants.gov”:">Grants.Gov</option>

            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

Thanks for any help and I appreciate you all taking the time to read this!

Comment: You are submitting the form & using the POST method, so "+" will not appear.Why do you want to add `+` sign?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use urlencode could you elaborate? As for the question the API I'm using requires each word in the search be separated by a + Sign.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and...?: 1) Share some sample output (actual/expected) so we can know what you mean 2) Explain the ultimate problem you have, and not only the cause you've figure out.

Comment: Ultimate problem is the search criteria needs to pass + signs onto the next page fboResults.php and does not.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Browser will internally encode data to satisfy  
application/x-www-form-urlencoded format but of course that's normally transparent as almost all server-side tools (esp. PHP) decode it automatically. Two things are unclear in this question: 1) How is it possible to break the browser form handling with plain HTML 2) Why it's exactly a problem.

Comment: @JohnChase Just seen your edit. When you're asked for further details we don't mean that you retype the previous information so it shows up twice...

Comment: Hmmm... *using the .POST function*... Is this by chance a jQuery question about AJAX?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm not 100% sure, I used similar code almost the exact code to pass the Search Criteria field via .POST to a PHP document when creating a separate API without issue. I have no idea why now unless I manually type the spaces the search doesn't work correctly. That's why I'm wondering if there is a way to manually set spaces to be seen as + signs.

Comment: UPDATE: On my PHP I'm passing the data to if I change .POST to .GET it seems the spaces are treated as + signs but the results the API returns are not nearly as accurate as leaving it set to .POST and manually adding the + signs between words.

Comment: But why do you add a leading dot to all HTTP method names? Is it true that you don't know if you are using JavaScript?

Comment: As an aside note, please, close the action attribute in your form tag: `<form name="search"` note the last double quote that you are missing in your original code

Comment: Found this link, it turns out the default for the API I'm using is to space words using boolean OR I need to escape that and switch to +.

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#+

Answer (score 1):

To encode the data you can use the unescape feature built into java script.
you can also use base64 to encode the data.

Or if you need it to be a encrypted you can encrypt it using your public encryption key and then have a piece of code to locally decode the data via your private key. For more information on this research 'Public, Private encryption keys.'

Answer (score 0):

When you deliver HTML to compose a form, let the user submit it and process it with PHP **you don't have to encode or decode data** yourself:

- The browser will encode it **automatically** for the user:

  [image: Encoded form]
- PHP will decode it **automatically** for you:

  ```
  var_dump($_POST['searchTerm']);
  ```

  > string(6) "1+2=3!"

Comment: How would I format that into my end link without breaking proper PHP format? Here's the end link.. https://api.data.gov/gsa/fbopen/v0/opps?q=".$_POST["searchTerm"]."&data_source

Comment: I suppose you don't mean that you work for the US Government... so you don't have control on the receiving end. Then you'll need to use JavaScript: you cannot control what the browser sends with HTML (which is a mark-up language) or PHP (which finished running long ago). Now, are you positively sure that the IT guys who work for Washington couldn't figure out how to deal with white spaces in their API?

Comment: I believe from reading the documentation they just set the white spaces to represent OR by default. If I don't manually add the + sign I can see it in the search results. So now my question has evolved and changed a bit, I'm trying to figure out how to override the lucene query syntax default they have in place. Apparently it's possible, I'm just lost in documentation :-(

Comment: The guy who wrote that piece of documentation for the Lucene project was referring to the actual search terms as received by his program. I can't imagine why you've reached the conclusion that you need to mess with application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST data, or the user form, or your computer's power supply. The user can type any text he wants and get it delivered as-is if you merely do nothing with it. Remove the custom code you've added that prevents that from happening and things will probably fix.

Comment: I realize it's supposed to do this on it's own but it doesn't. If I were to type "Test Search One" no results are returned or highly in accurate ones. If I type "Test+Search+One" then exact results are returned. This is what I'd like my users to achieve without manually having to enter the pluses.

Comment: I suspect you treat the whole process as a black box (type something, get something) which is not. You have lots of helper tools to inspect data almost anywhere in the flow: browser *Net* pane, PHP `var_dump()` and many others.